# Crash when calling performSegueWithIdentifier with verified segue identifier string

Tags: objective-c, ios7, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I added a "Done" button to my navigation bar programmatically since I couldn't do it on the storyboard.

Next, I wanted to link from this "Done" button to another subclass of UICollectionViewController (both destination and source view controllers are subclasses of UICollectionViewController).

Since, my "Done" button couldn't show up on the storyboard (because added programmatically), I created a new "Done" button on the storyboard just in the purpose of being able to generate a segue identifier between the two view controllers. I assigned the string "donePressed" to the segue identifier as you can see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sd936ml1iably3/donePressed_segue_identifier.png

When I run my build, it succeeds but when I tap on the "Done" button in my navigation bar, I get the following error message: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5fdg9xs886hxod/Error_Message_performSegueWithIdentifier.png

In essence, it is telling me that my source view controller has no segue with the "donePressed" identifier.

This is weird to me since I purposely created the segue and when I double check my code calling the "performSegueWithIdentifier" method, it looks like I have entered the right "donePressed" NSString.

See here this line of code:

```
-(void)donePressed {
    //segue to other VC
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"donePressed" sender:self.doneButton];

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help much appreciated.

Merci!

Comment: Does THFriendsViewControleller have the segue name `donePressed`? The error message means that there's no segue of `donePressed`.

Answer (score 0):

The segue you have created looks like it is from your "Done" button to the next ViewController, not from `self` (primary view controller) to your next view controller. If you have linked the "Done" button to perform the segue all in storyboard, you should not need to write any programmatic code to perform the segue.